# How to ensure expressions that evaluate to floats, give the expected integer value with int(*)

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

In this question's most general form, I want to know how I can guarantee that `int(x * y)` (with `x` and `y` both being `float`s gives me the arithmetically "correct" answer when I know the result to be a round number. For example: 1.5 * 2.0 = 3, or 16.0 / 2.0 = 8. I worry this could be a problem because `int` can round down if there is some floating point error. For example: `int(16.0 - 5 * sys.float_info.epsilon)` gives `15`.

And specializing the question a bit, I could also ask about division between two `int`s where I know the result is a round number. For example 16 / 2 = 8. If this specialization changes the answer to the more general question, I'd like to know how.

By the way, I know that I could do `int(round(x * y)`. I'm just wondering if there's a more direct built-in, or if there's some proven guarantee that means I don't have to worry about this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If both inputs are exact, and the mathematically correct result is representable, then the output is also guaranteed to be exact. This is only true for a limited number of basic floating-point operations, but `*` and `/` are such operations.

Note that the "both inputs are exact" condition is only satisfiable for [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational). Numbers like 1.5 are fine, but numbers like 0.1 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point. Also, floating point precision limits apply to integers, too, not just fractional values - very large integers may not be exactly representable, due to requiring more precision than a Python `float` has.

Comment: Right so it sounds like I have the guarantee for some specific situations but overall it's better to use `int(round(*))` to cover all bases. Although I suppose this wouldn't necessarily cover **all** bases like the large number example you gave.